# Check if write session in blocked

Tags: php, session

Php provides function [`session_write_close`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php). I want to check if session has been closed. `session_id()` still returns value.

```
session_start();

//
// Some code there
//

session_write_close();

//
// Some code there
//

if( /*is session write closed?*/)
    echo 'Session closed';
else
    echo 'Session still opened';
```

Comment: Are you trying to kill the session? If so, then there are a few other ways to do that. Please describe your problem...

Comment: `session_write_close()` helps me with fix one bug. I've discovered this function and now i'm just curious and i want to increase my knowledge about php sessions. That's why i created this question - it's imagined problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have PHP version 5.4.0 or greater, you can use [session_status()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php).

Answer (score 2):

All you need is

```
session_start();
session_write_close();
var_dump(sessionStatus()); // this would return false
```

And

```
session_start();
var_dump(sessionStatus()); // true
```

Function Used

```
function sessionStatus() {
    if (function_exists('session_status')) {
        return (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE);
    }
    return defined('SID');
}
```

Comment: On my systems (php 5.4.11 and 5.3.21), the `SID` constant seem to behave just like `session_id()` and it's still defined and holds the session id after the `session_write_close()`.